# List to a dataframe with a shift in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new at Stack overflow. Please, I am trying to get the Levenshtein distance from an amino acid sequence with different motifs.
So, I got a list like the following example. I would like to know how to arrange the list on a data frame shifting one column to the right every "N" rows. In the example, N=3 and I would like to change the N by any value. I am using python Thanks.

[image: amino acid sequence]

Comment: what does your desired output look like?

Comment: Hello Ehsan. I wonder if you are able to see the output that I want in the image but it should be a dataframe with a shift every N columns (3 columns in this example). Something like the image 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you asked for data frames, you can use the `df.shift(periods=n, axis=1)` in pandas. E.g.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

n = 3
List1 = ['1', '5', '2', '3', '1', '3', '1', '3', '0', '0', '5', '1']
List2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [List1] * n +  [[np.nan] * len(List1)] * n).transpose()
df.columns = List2

for x in range(0, len(List1), n):
    df.loc[x:(x+n-1)] = df.loc[x:(x+n-1)].shift(periods = x // n, axis = 1)

df
```

Will give you:

```
      A    B    C    D    E    F
0     1    1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     5    5    5  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     2    2    2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN    3    3    3  NaN  NaN
4   NaN    1    1    1  NaN  NaN
5   NaN    3    3    3  NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN    1    1    1  NaN
7   NaN  NaN    3    3    3  NaN
8   NaN  NaN    0    0    0  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN    0    0    0
10  NaN  NaN  NaN    5    5    5
11  NaN  NaN  NaN    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) which store for each letter the column of the given table:

```py
n = 3
list1 = [1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 5, 1]
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

table = dict()

for i, letter in enumerate(list2):
    start = max(0, n * (i - n + 1))
    end = min(len(list1), n * (i + 1))
    table[letter] = [None] * start \
            + list1[start:end] \
            + [None] * (len(list1) - end)

print(table)
```

which outputs

```
{'A': [1, 5, 2, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'B': [1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'C': [1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0, None, None, None], 'D': [None, None, None, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 5, 1], 'E': [None, None, None, None, None, None, 1, 3, 0, 0, 5, 1], 'F': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 0, 5, 1]}
```

With a *pretty print*, it is possible to recreate the given table:

```py
print(' ' + ' '.join(list2))
for i in range(len(list1)):
    line = ""
    for letter in list2:
        s = table[letter][i]
        line += f"{s:2d}" if s is not None else "  "
    print(line)
```

which prints

```
 A B C D E F
 1 1 1
 5 5 5
 2 2 2
   3 3 3
   1 1 1
   3 3 3
     1 1 1
     3 3 3
     0 0 0
       0 0 0
       5 5 5
       1 1 1
```